# WCF 3.0 WebService + CRUD

Tags: wcf, crud, .net-3.0

I'm going to create WCF web service using .net framework 3.0.
This web service will expose CRUD operation to database as well as it will have some web methods that consume other web services to provide service. I have decided to create separate class library for CRUD functionality.
I want to know best practices for this type of requirement. How can I structure the Web Service architecture and Class library? How can I use the repository pattern and expose it to the web methods? 
I can use only .NET 3.0.

Comment: This is a design related question and not a specific programming question. I suggest moving it to meta.stackoverflow.com. See this [SO thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55138/where-to-ask-design-related-questions).

Comment: @channs meta is for questions about SO.  This question is not a good fit for meta.  I'd say it is a fine question for SO.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just going to expose CRUD operations for a DB through WCF, you might want to just use [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx) (unless they renamed it yet again).  It might save you some setup time.